# how to use hashbytes() when create select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I want to convert Password from **varchar** to **binary**.

I have the query like,

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Table2(Username,password)values('+
IsNull(''''+wl.UserName+'''', 'NULL')+','+
     HASHBYTES('MD5',ISNULL(wl.Password,'NULL'))+')'
```

But i have error when i execute the above code,

```
  The data types nvarchar and varbinary are incompatible in the add operator.
```

I need your help. My query is correct. why it is show like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Table2(Username,password)values('+
IsNull(''''+wl.UserName+'''', 'NULL')+','+
      isnull('0x' + cast('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:column("password") )', 'varchar(max)'),'NULL') + ')'
from (select username, hashbytes('md5',password) as password from wl) wl
```

Reference: [Converting from hex string to varbinary and vice versa](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx)